# elasticsearch mapping for products

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine

i want to implement a search engine for my online shopping site
i test a few analyzers but i didn't see significance difference between them.i used snowball,ngram,standard analyzers
i don't know for the products name which analyzer suits and give me the best results,also i don't know which search query i should use
this is my schema for mapping

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "snowball": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "snowball"
                        },
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

and search query,i don't know using match query is good or not for my usecase

```
{
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "fuzziness":2,
                "type" : "phrase",
                "query": "term",
                "fields": ["name", "name.snowball",
                    "name.autocomplete"]
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see what tokens are generated in the Lucene index for the different analyzers that you use. The query 'term' is not a good example to test with, use something a bit longer.

What are the requirements for your search?

Don't use the multi-match query to test the results, test the analyzers in individual searches.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?q=name:yourSearchTerm'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?q=name.snowball:yourSearchTerm'

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?q=name.autocomplete:yourSearchTerm'
```

For autocomplete have a look at the [Completion Suggesster API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/you-complete-me/).

Also, the Snowball stemmer is quite aggressive and can produce undesirable results, you may want to use a lighter stemmer.

Comment: i haven't any special requirements,just a search engine to index all products name,so which analyzer is better do you think?you say that i don't use match_query?so which query do you recommended that suits me?

Comment: To test the queries I say don't use multi_match query as you want see any difference between the searches. If you haven't got any special requirements just the use the Standard Analyzer (the default), and build from that if you need to. Use the multi_match if you need to search on more than one field, or have a look at the match query http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: but i want the search engine to be powerful.for searching which query do you recommend?fuzzy,match,match+fuzziness, what?

Comment: It is difficult to recommend a type of query without knowing your exact use-case and search features. So as @DanTuffery suggests, start with the Standard Analyzer and use the simple Match Query for the first steps. And then slowly improve your search.